# WPF + get value of datagridview

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview

Here's my wpf xml datagridview:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CustomLimitationTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox>
            <ComboBoxItem>Aucune</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Légère</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Modérée</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Forte</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Totale</ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="2" Name="dg1" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource XmlData},XPath=Limits/*}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" x:Name="IdColumn" Binding="{Binding XPath=Id}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Capacite" CellTemplate="{StaticResource CustomCapacityTemplate}" Width="480" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Limitation" x:Name="LimitationColumn" CellTemplate="{StaticResource CustomLimitationTemplate}" Width="150" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Aide" CellTemplate="{StaticResource CustomDetailTemplate}" Width="97" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I want to get all first (ID) and third (Limitation, the DataTemplate Combobox) value but all my foreach and for loop failed. Example:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dg1.SelectedRows)
{
    var id = row[IdColumn].ToString();
    var limitations = row[LimitationColumn].ToString();
}
```

Comment: What is the run time error you are getting?

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS1061 'DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedRows' and no extension method 'SelectedRows' accepting a first argument of type 'DataGrid' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn' to 'int'
Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTemplateColumn' to 'int

Comment: So there are the compile time exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use datarow to access datagrid combobox values in wpf.
You can get the any selected column by following code.

Add the following xaml view

**DataGrid**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgTest" HorizontalAlignment="Left" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="37,152,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="126" Width="440" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=data/Limits}" SelectionChanged="dgTest_SelectionChanged">
            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomDetailTemplate">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <ComboBox SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged_1" Loaded="ComboBox_Loaded_2" >
                            <ComboBoxItem>Aucune</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>Légère</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>Modérée</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>Forte</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>Totale</ComboBoxItem>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>

                <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomLimitationTemplate">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <ComboBox SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged_2" Loaded="ComboBox_Loaded_1" > 
                            <ComboBoxItem>01</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>02</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>03</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>04</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>05</ComboBoxItem>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="CustomCapacityTemplate">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <ComboBox Loaded="ComboBox_Loaded_3" >
                            <ComboBoxItem>11</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>12</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>13</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>14</ComboBoxItem>
                            <ComboBoxItem>15</ComboBoxItem>
                        </ComboBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" x:Name="IdColumn" Binding="{Binding XPath=Id}" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Capacite" CellTemplate="{StaticResource CustomCapacityTemplate}" Width="100" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Limitation" x:Name="LimitationColumn" CellTemplate="{StaticResource CustomLimitationTemplate}" Width="150" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Aide" CellTemplate="{StaticResource CustomDetailTemplate}" Width="97" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

**xml definition**

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Name="TestData" Source="test.xml"/>
    </Window.DataContext>
```

Now, declare the following instances and variable gloabally.

```
ComboBox cmb02;
ComboBox cmb01;
ComboBox cmb03;
string cmb1, cmb2,cmb3;
```

Now, add the following code to combo-box's load event

```
private void ComboBox_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            cmb01 = (sender as ComboBox);
            cmb01.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        private void ComboBox_Loaded_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            cmb02 = (sender as ComboBox);
            cmb02.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        private void ComboBox_Loaded_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            cmb03 = (sender as ComboBox);
            cmb03.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
```

Finally add the following codes to datagrid selected changed event

```
private void dgTest_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (cmb01 != null && cmb02 != null && cmb03 !=null)
            {
                cmb1 = cmb01.SelectionBoxItem.ToString();
                cmb2 = cmb02.SelectionBoxItem.ToString();
                cmb3 = cmb03.SelectionBoxItem.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(cmb1 + cmb2+cmb3);
            }
        }
```

Here I used messagebox for displaying purpose. You can handle the output whatever the way you want.

Hope this answer helps you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Little help yes, but i don't know how to get all row ? by a for on my datagrid ?

Comment: @Leucomelas Hope following link help you http://blog.scottlogic.com/2008/12/02/wpf-datagrid-detecting-clicked-cell-and-row.html